# JAXB Java EE generate entity class from Schema

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I'm using the Maven plugin for JAXB to generate classes from an XML schema document. 
My POM contains the following

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
     <executions>
 <execution>
     <goals>
 <goal>xjc</goal>
 </goals>
 <phase>generate-sources</phase>
     </execution>
   </executions>
 <configuration>
 <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
 <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
 <schemaDirectory>src/main/webapp/schemas</schemaDirectory>
 <includeSchema>**/*.xsd</includeSchema>
 <bindingDirectory>src/main/resources/bindings</bindingDirectory>
 <enableIntrospection>false</enableIntrospection>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I'm using the Eclipselink specification of JPA 2. When JAXB generates the class according to the schema, it does not include the following annotations.

```
@Entity
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

At the moment I just manually add these in every time I do a clean compile with Maven. I'm wondering if there is anyway to get the JAXB plugin to annotate the class file with these annotations included when it generates the classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XJC compiler used by JAXB has a plugin api which allows to customize the generated java code. There seems to be a [plugin to add arbitrary annotations](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Annotate+Plugin), maybe this already solves your problem.

For a more complex example of the possibilities you could look at the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/jaxb-fluent-api-ext/source/browse/code/trunk/src/main/java/redmosquito/xjc/plugin/fluent/ext/FluentApiExtPlugin.java) of the [fluent api plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jaxb-fluent-api-ext/).